# Form validation error... error displayed, but clicking OK on error box, triggers form submit...

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I'm trying to add form validation / error messages on my website rental form.  I'm not sure what wrong here.  When I click submit (if form is blank) the error box does show and say the errors, BUT, once you click OK on this error box, it submits the form and loads the thank you page.  The 'return false' in the function doesn't seem to be working.  I'm trying to get the error box to close when you click OK, then return to the unsent form to fix / fill in the missing fields.

It is a very large form, so I'll just display the key areas for review... 
Thank you all so much for any assistance!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

function checkforblank() {

```
var errormessage = "";

if (document.getElementById('Full Name').value == "") {
    errormessage += "Please enter your Full Name \n";
    }

if (document.getElementById('Address').value == "") {
    errormessage += "Please enter your Address \n";
    }

if (document.getElementById('Home Phone').value == "") {
    errormessage += "Please enter your Home Phone Number \n";
    }

if (document.getElementById('EventPhone').value == "") {
    errormessage += "Please enter your Event Phone Number \n";
    }

if (document.getElementById('Email Address').value == "") {
    errormessage += "Please enter your Email Address \n";
    }

if (document.getElementById('Number').value == "") {
    errormessage += "Please enter your Card Number \n";
    }

if (document.getElementById('NumberB').value == "") {
    errormessage += "Please enter your Card Number \n";
    }

if (document.getElementById('NumberC').value == "") {
    errormessage += "Please enter your Card Number \n";
    }

if (document.getElementById('NumberD').value == "") {
    errormessage += "Please enter your Card Number \n";
    }

if (document.getElementById('ExpMonth').value == "") {
    errormessage += "Please enter your Cards Exp Date MMYY \n";
    }

if (document.getElementById('ExpYear').value == "") {
    errormessage += "Please enter your Cards Billing Zip \n";
    }

if (document.getElementById('Accept Rental Agreement').value == "") {
    errormessage += "Please type ACCEPT in the box \n";
    }   

if (errormessage != "") {
    alert(errormessage); 
    return false;
    }else return true;                                          
}
```

Here is the code used in the submit button:

```
 <input type=submit onclick="checkforblank();" value='RESERVE NOW' style="font-family: Arial" class="style106">
```

And here's the form starting code:

```
 <form onsubmit="return checkforblank();" method="post" action="http://jumpnplayparty.com/ftools/process.php"  language="JavaScript" name="FrontPage_Form1">
```

I'm learning... sorry if code is messy :p  Searched several posts on this topic / several youtube videos, but still no luck after 10+ hours of tinkering with the form... Please help

See full form here: https://ink.mysitehosted.com/~bounce/MAMoonwalkRentals/Mobile/reserve_mobile_form.htm

Thanks for your help!

Comment: In Chrome I do not see the behavior you described when visiting your example URL. The alert shows up, and after confirming it by clicking OK nothing happens, the form is not send.

Comment: But there are syntax errors in your script, f.e. in your function `FrontPage_Form1_Validator`, the line `if (theForm.Full Name.value == "")` is wrong – you can not simply have a space character in that expression there, that makes it invalid. If you have spaces in your form element names, then you must use the following syntax to address them: `theForm["Full Name"].value` – that is the only way you can access properties that include spaces in the name in JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are syntax errors in your script, f.e. in your function `FrontPage_Form1_Validator`, the line

```
if (theForm.Full Name.value == "")
```

is wrong – you can not simply have a space character in that expression there, that makes it invalid.

If you have spaces in your form element names, then you must use the following syntax to address them: `theForm["Full Name"].value` – that is the only way you can access properties that include spaces in the name in JS.